# Iterate over S3 bucket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3

How to iterate Amazon S3 file partially?

In the code below

```
 GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(
        bucket, key);
rangeObjectRequest.setRange(0, 10);

S3Object objectPortion = amazonS3Client.getObject(rangeObjectRequest);
```

As per the documentation, I can only enter values from 0 to 9.

> /* The first byte in an object has
>        position 0; as an example, the first ten bytes of an object can be
>        downloaded by specifying a range of 0 to 9.*/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overlooking the significance of the phrase **"as an example"**.

If you want to read the first 10 bytes, you start at offset 0 and stop after offset 9.  If you want the 101st through 200th byte, the values would be 100, 199 (the first byte is offset 0).

Any values < the total number of bytes in the object are valid.